# Using the period character in YAML 1.2 regex

Tags: yaml

I must be missing something here, YAML 1.2 documentation doesn't seem to mention this so I figured I'd ask here.

Consider the below snippet from my YAML file

```
- match: '(dns_[a-z_]+|tls_(cert[a-z_]+)|tls.subject)'
```

How do I ensure that the period is matched literally?  I've tried all sorts of escapes and even tried to specify the hex value but, it's never seen by YAML and thus isn't matching tls.subject, ever.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm looking through examples and people are using backslash without an issue, yet it's not working for me here.

Comment: Turns out there was a clash with another match I had above.  I've made a workaround for that and now backslash is working as intended.